# cudnn can't be installed when i used .deb format

Tags: cudnn

My nvidia driver is
`NVRM version: NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  384.130  Wed Mar 21 03:37:26 PDT 2018`
And my cuda version is

```
 nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver 
 Copyright (c) 2005-2017 NVIDIA Corporation
 Built on Fri_Sep__1_21:08:03_CDT_2017
 Cuda compilation tools, release 9.0, V9.0.176
```

I'm sure i have install the nvidia-driver and cuda in the right way,and i want to install cudnn with 'libcudnn7_7.5.0.56-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb'. I typed in `'sudo dpkg -i libcudnn7_7.5.0.56-1+cuda9.0_amd64.deb`' in terminal but when i tested with `cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2` ,it shows that `cat: /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h: No such file or directory`,i think i fail to install cudnn.I try to double click the .deb file to install ,and i did choose the 'install' option,but it also shows `cat: /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h: No such file or directory`, so I don't know what to do .I can't find cudnn.h in any cuda file.
BTW I can't find the other cudnn file in .tar or .tar.gz format .
thank a lot.

Comment: When you install Cudnn using deb file you can find out the Cudnn version using : `sudo apt search cudnn | grep installed` and not `cat /usr/local/cuda/include/cudnn.h | grep CUDNN_MAJOR -A 2`. The later command is if you use tar file and not deb file.

Answer (score -1):

I know what's wrong!! My system was inatalled with ubuntu16.04.I downloaded the cudnn for ubuntu16.04 before and it always show nothing.This time i download the cudnn for linux and it success.